# SUSY static grid, but with set widths according to resolution

Tags: css, compass-sass, susy-compass

I am quite new to web grid systems but would like to choose SUSY mainly because so many people recommend it.  What I'd like to achieve is something similar to what I see with the grid system in Twitter bootstrap, where the columns are not fluid in width, but the entire grid width has two or three pre-defined widths based on available resolution.

So, for example, I'd like to have an 8 column grid, with a grid width of 1140px if available, else 960px.

I was able to come up with something similar with SUSY, where my max container width was 1140px, and by setting a min-width of 960px it would never resize below that, but the grid was fluid between the two and my preference is for it to simple switch from one to the other when the resolution becomes available.  This is mainly to have 2 or 3 predictable layouts.

Many thanks if anyone can help.
Chris Chandler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use Susy's `static` output. To do that, set `$container-style: static;`. [See the docs on the official Susy site](http://susy.oddbird.net/guides/reference/#ref-container-style).

Comment: Hi Eric. Thanks for your answer, but I don't think is quite what I need.  It seems to me that a static grid is prefixed at one set resolution.  Essentially what I'd like is three static grids, all with the same column layout, but differing widths for each column, and only switching between these grids when resolution allows.

Comment: So for example, it configures itself as an 1140 static grid if 1140px is available, but drops to a 960 static grid if not.  This seems to be a pretty common solution, and I think the default "responsive" behaviour of Twitter Bootstrap grid.

Comment: Static grids will adjust to media-query breakpoints in exactly the same way that fluid/magic grids do. Just use `at-breakpoint` to change the grid settings at different viewport sizes, and you have what you need.

Comment: You do need to set the container at each breakpoint, either using the the shortcut for media-queries in the `container` mixin, or by repeating that mixin at each different breakpoint.

Comment: Thanks Eric. It took me a little experimentation to get this right, but got there in the end.